# Doxygen Dot Generates Boxes Instead of Names

Tags: doxygen, dot

I'm trying to visualize a code base without explicit doxygen comments, I run into what seems like an error when viewing the dot graphs in the html generated by doxygen [Generated Boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQpvX.png)
I'm running doxygen under a cygwin bash with GraphViz installed. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured it out...the blank boxes should have been a dead give away that the problem was with a missing font dependency. I installed a different version of GraphViz that had the font dependency resolved under mingw.